# Spring Cloud/Boot vs Wildfly Swarm

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, wildfly-9, wildfly-swarm

I have doing some analysis of modern Container less Java Stack on net, two Major promising things i came about was:

1. Spring Boot/Cloud (Packed in Tomcat or Jetty,...)
2. Wildfly Swarm (Moduler Wildfly 9 Server with minimum possible components)

Yes both have their own features but i have not been able to find out a good comparison of both as both thing are in my point of view better then each other but still i have to decide what good for implementing,

1. Good for Developer health
2. Complex Enterprise logic
3. Scalability
4. Hot deployments
5. Microservice Approach
6. Enterprise Integration Patterns
7. Continuous Delivery Pipeline.

Thanks for your thoughts

Zaheer

Comment: The container that you will be running on will not help you with any of your 7 items. Each one comes from different mindset, if you fell comfortable developing with spring go for Spring Boot, Wildfly I would say that is more suitable for those who prefer Java EE (jaxrs, cdi etc). One important point that should be considered is how easy is to configure these two, no thoughts on that though

Comment: Thanks for answer and time, till now hat i have expeirenced is Spring Boot is bit easy and yes when i gone use EJB stack then better to use wildfly stack.

Comment: Spring boot is easier than Swarm indeed. Swarm is too recent and I noticed that the memory usage is way too high than I was expecting. Besides that I still don't see too many advantages on deploying an embedded container. Wildfly has low memory footprint. Have a look on this video, it may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-r9bU3y3Y0 . Good luck

Comment: I would also use Spring boot due to Spring Boot is a little bit longer in the fat-jar business and has a better ecosystem. For example you can choose between tomcat, jetty, undertow,... inside your application. You mentioned also Enterprise Integration Patterns. In Spring Boot you can choose between Spring Integration or Apache Camel. They even support Apache Camel on their start.spring.io site (which is cool because it is the direct competitor to Spring Integration)

IMO if you are bound to Wildfly you will be bound to J2EE - and the Spring guys are moving way faster than the J2EE guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Spring Boot because it's more popular, has good documentation/examples and more support on Stack Overflow. Also provides convenient tools for testing. Some comparisons:

- [The lightweightness of microservices – Comparing Spring Boot, WildFly Swarm, and Haskell Snap](https://blog.akquinet.de/2017/01/12/the-lightweightness-of-microservices-comparing-spring-boot-wildly-swarm-and-haskell-snap/)
- [Spring Boot vs WildFly Swarm In the Land of Enterprise Java](https://medium.com/@dersoz/spring-boot-vs-wildfly-swarm-in-the-land-of-enterprise-java-4ebd210fbc4a)
- [WildFly Swarm vs Spring Boot](http://ksoong.org/wildfly-swarm-spring-boot)